# Laravel 5.2: Eloquent undefined property

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

In one of my projects I use Laravel. In my view I use:

```
{{ $intro->inhoud}}
```

And this returns: 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$inhoud (View: D:\Web\Ampps\www\mca.app\resources\views\frontend\huisartsen.blade.php)

However, when I use:

```
{{ $intro }}
```

I get the entire intro object, with "inhoud" being one of the keys:

```
[{"id":1,
"inhoud":"Bacon ipsum dolor amet brisket pork loin hamburger ham tenderloin, spare ribs pork chop meatloaf. Hamburger pig strip steak tri-tip doner pastrami prosciutto picanha shank pork chop. Strip steak rump doner chuck sirloin prosciutto swine andouille picanha landjaeger cupim jerky. Venison tongue rump, tri-tip boudin fatback salami sausage. Capicola boudin kielbasa, tri-tip swine t-bone leberkas corned beef. Sausage meatball chuck, boudin pork belly cow jowl andouille salami turkey.",
"pagina":"huisartsen",
"created_at":null,
"updated_at":null}]
```

Anyone any idea why I cannot use

```
{{ $intro->inhoud }}
```

or even

```
{{ $intro["inhoud"] }}
```

Thanks a lot from a starting Laravel developer!

Comment: dd($intro) what output come..?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [@Burak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3029171/burak), thanks to you I found the solution!

The problem was in my controller, where I did this:

```
$intro = App\Intro::where('pagina', '=', 'huisartsen')->get();
```

And that gave me an array.
By changing it to this:

```
$intro = App\Intro::where('pagina', '=', 'huisartsen')->first();
```

It gave me the object I wanted so now I can use

```
{{ $intro->inhoud }}
```

Comment: `->get()` returns a collection, so in order to access collection's objects, you need to loop through it (`foreach`), no matter if it contains 1 or more objects. however, if you need just a single record retrieved, then `->first()` is the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `json_decode($intro)` as it seems to me that this is JSON object